# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible when calling Oracle stored procedure from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have used integer array to Pass values to Oracle stored procedure

> Data type in Oracle => Number

**stored procedure :**

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE SP_ACCESS
    (
           UserID IN CHECKINOUT.USERID%TYPE  
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO CHECKINOUT ("USERID")
      VALUES (UserID);
      COMMIT;
    END;
```

**ASP.NET Code :**

```
            int[] arrUID = UID.ToArray();
            OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = Obj.GetOraConnectionString();
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "SP_ACCESS";
            command.Parameters.Add("@USERID", OracleDbType.Int32);
            command.Parameters[0].Value = arrUID;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

While executing i got the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: `command.Parameters[0].Value` is expecting a `System.Int32` type, you're assigning a `System.Int32[]` (**array of int's**)

Comment: You can’t pass an array as parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines below causing exception because `OracleCommand` parameter expects data type of `int`, while you're passing value of `int[]` array (also array binding is not used by default).

```
command.Parameters.Add("@USERID", OracleDbType.Int32);
command.Parameters[0].Value = arrUID;
```

If you just want to pass single element, use array index number to assign value.

```
command.Parameters[0].Value = arrUID[0];
```

However if you want to pass entire array contents into stored procedure parameter, try setting `OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` to `CollectionType` property before assigning value (**side note:** possible requires schema level type to be declared first before using in stored procedure, see reference (1)):

```
command.Parameters.Add("@USERID", OracleDbType.Int32);
command.Parameters[0].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
command.Parameters[0].Value = arrUID;

// ExecuteNonQuery afterwards
```

Or simply setting [`ArrayBindCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/CommandArrayBindCount.html#GUID-04A4E08E-E2C5-435A-9476-9ECDE83C90BC) property before assigning parameter value:

```
command.BindByName = true;
command.ArrayBindCount = UID.Count; // assumed UID is a List<int>
command.Parameters.Add("@USERID", OracleDbType.Int32);
command.Parameters[0].Value = arrUID;

// ExecuteNonQuery afterwards
```

Additional references:

(1) [C# 2010, ODP.net, call stored procedure passing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201743/c-sharp-2010-odp-net-call-stored-procedure-passing-array)

(2) [Oracle stored procedure using array as parameter for table insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677746/oracle-stored-procedure-using-array-as-parameter-for-table-insert)

(3) [Pass a list of integers from C# into Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308076/pass-a-list-of-integers-from-c-sharp-into-oracle-stored-procedure)